# How to recover Adium ICQ contacts when the account is locked

Tags: macos, data-recovery, contacts, adium

I recently got locked out of my 10+ year old ICQ account for no good reason — the password just stopped working one day. Password recovery doesn't work and I never gave them an email address anyway (at least that's what I think, it's been a while).

---

When I start Adium, it asks for a password I am unable to provide. Unfortunately, it only displays those contacts for accounts that are connected or connecting. All my ICQ contacts are missing from the contact list

How can I recover the ICQ account numbers and some identifying information about those users?

Comment: While I answered the question myself, I'm open towards better solutions. They might not be *that* helpful for me anymore, but still, there's got to be something better...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adium user account information is stored in `/Users/danielbeck/Library/Application Support/Adium 2.0/Users/Default` or possibly, AFAIK, one of the sibling folders.

---

It seems they stored contact information in individual files in the directory `ByObject` (until late 2008), but switched to the single file `ByObjectPrefs.plist` since then.

While the directory `libpurple` contains a `blist.xml` (buddy list), it doesn't contain Adium's user aliases, only the contact's last self-assigned user name, which is usually not all that useful, depending on the people.

---

`ByObjectPrefs.plist` is a binary `plist file. Create a copy and convert in Terminal to XML using

> `plutil -convert xml1 /Users/danielbeck/Library/Application\ Support/Adium\ 2.0/Users/Default/ByObjectPrefs\ Copy.plist`

Unfortunately, I was unable to properly automatically read its format so far. Copy&paste directly from the file is painful, but it somewhat works.

---

I recovered the contacts using the following expression:

> `cat ByObjectPrefs\ 2.plist | grep -A 15 -P "^\t<key>ICQ" | grep -v "<dict>" | grep -v "</dict>" | sed "s| *<[^>]*>||g" | sed 's|ICQ\.||' | grep -v "Alias" | grep -v "ICQAlias`

It prints the file, searches for occurrences of `<key>ICQ`, strips the XML from the lines following that and prints them. One such entry looks like this (fantasy values to protect the innocent):

```
314159265
    Firstname Lastname
    Last Seen Date
    2011-03-05T15:56:59Z
    Last Seen Status
    Signing off
    Preferred Account
    2
```

While this somewhat worked, I'm not even sure it matched all contacts. Some entries had no identifying information (ignored spammers?), etc. I'm looking forward to a better solution.